# Как правильно организовать цикл each?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Почему у меня не работает такой перебор:

```
$('#div').children('li').children('a').each(index) {
    //тело цикла
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем такой изврат?

```
$('#div>li>a').each(function(index){ /* code */ });
```

Comment: это не то же самое :)

$('#div > li > a').each(function(index){ /* code */ });

тогда уж

Comment: Принято) Никогда `children()` не пользовался, `find()` всегда хватало.

Comment: по идее children() должно быстрее работать. Ищет оно строго среди прямых потомков.
Есть смысл в определённых случаях использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Может из-за синтаксичесской ошибки?

```
$('#div>li>a').each(function(index){ тело цикла })
```